# How to import Bengali font from a csv file using python 3?

Tags: python, csv

I have stored a csv file on my pc. I want to import data from csv file using python 3. If I import any English data from that csv, it's just working fine! But when I tried with Bengali fonts, it's just showing '???' mark rather than showing the Bengali text.

```
import csv
myFile = open('demo.csv')
myReader = csv.reader(myFile)
for row in myReader:
    print('Row #' + str(myReader.line_num) + ' ' + str(row))
```

And I'm getting this output:

```
Row #1 ['???? ', '???? ', '???? ', '????? ', '????']
Row #2 ['????? ', '????????? ', '????? ', '?????????? ', '???????? ']
Row #3 ['??', '??', '??', '??', '??']
```

If I want to display Bengali font correctly, What would be the proper code?

Answer (score 0):

Just what do you mean by "Bengali font"? A font is a way to display characters, but a font is not stored in a text file. A file stores characters, not fonts.

Do you mean [Bengali *characters*](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0980.pdf)? If so, decode each row from its text format [into a Unicode string](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/unicode.html), then print that string. The output device will have the responsibility to show the text correctly--but it may not be able to do that, depending on the output device.

Let us know if you need more detail on decoding text to a Unicode string. Note that the version of Python matters here: Python 2 handles Unicode differently than Python 3. If you plan to use international characters often, use Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Unicode characters can't be saved in a CSV file.

However, when trying to save a CSV file with Unicode characters, the editor will prompt a warning message, and the saved characters will be displayed as question marks (??)!

In the end, the Python CSV package will read the file's content with question marks (??).

```
myReader = csv.reader(myFile)
```